# Have any movies or TV shows been dubbed into Klingon?

Tags: klingon-language

I've been reading questions on here recently about the Klingon language, and how works of literature have been or are being translated into it. Taken a step further, have any movies or TV shows been translated and then dubbed into Klingon?

I for one, would love to hear a Klingon rendition of the *Beverly Hillbillies* theme.

Comment: The *Galaxy Quest* DVD includes a Thermian audio track. I tried to listen to it once. I didn't make it past five minutes.

Comment: Star Wreck was subtitled into Klingon, but not dubbed; http://www.starwreck.com/smf/index.php?topic=1935.0